# rails console - no such file to load -- readline (LoadError) [ubuntu 11.10]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, console, readline

I'm new to ruby on rails. When I use the command: **rails console**, it comes the problem: "*no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)*"

```
   /home/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `require': no such file to load -- readline (LoadError)
        from /home/<username>/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/irb/completion.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `require'
        from /home/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
        from /home/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `require'
        from /home/<username>/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:38:in `<top (required)>'
        from script/rails:6:in `require'
        from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

So I searched google, and followed this http://rails3blog.com/2010/09/error-no-such-file-to-load-readline-loaderror/, but it didn't work for me.

My OS is *Ubuntu 11.10* with *Ruby 1.9.2p290* and *Rails 3.2.1*

PS: I have install the readline with the command: **rvm --skip-autoreconf pkg install readline.**

PS:i have solved the problem after a long time search,the answer is under below:

1) ensure you have installed ubuntus readline and editline dev packages

sudo apt-get install libreadline6 libreadline6-dev

2) configure ruby's readline extension to use the systems libs, not rvm's packages

`rvm pkg uninstall readline`
`cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.2-p290/ext/readline`
`ruby extconf.rb --with-editline-dir=/usr/ --with-readline-dir=/usr/`
`make`
`make install`

3) go to your project and start up the rails console

here is the answer's link : [can't get "rails console" to work on ubuntu 11.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8583224/cant-get-rails-console-to-work-on-ubuntu-11-10)

Answer (score 1):

The above error points to the **require 'readline'** statement in line 9 of *completion.rb*

The **readline** library is not properly installed in your system. You might need to install a *libreadline-dev* package in ubuntu for it.

Follow this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4385549/no-such-file-to-load-readline) for ways solve '*no such file to load — readline*' error.

Comment: i have already install the libreadline6-dev for my ubuntu, but it didn't work either...